# sentence omits subject

Tags: subjects

How is this grammar works?

In resume:

I lead a group of three developers and ...

→ Led group of three developers and ...

Is this a `past participle` or [Ellipsis](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis) (it just omits subject)?

Is it just omits subject?

I *was led* group of three developers and ...

becomes

*Led* group of three developers and ...

---

And a example likes this in Google Play:

Added reading progress bar

---

Is this a telegram style?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Is it a _Conversational Deletion_? `I was led group of three developers and ...` becomes → `Led group of three developers and ...`; `We were added reading progress bar`  becomes → `Added reading progress bar`?

Comment: 'I was led group ...' is ungrammatical and so impossible to analyse. I'm replying to your title.